# Symfony2 Installer Issue (2.7)

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to install SF2 2.7 version and when I follow the steps here to install Symfony Installer:

```
php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony
```

It does not install SF2 and gives the errors:

```
G:\>symfony new alfa
'symfony' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
 operable program or batch file.
```

When I try this command:

```
G:\>php symfony

Warning: readfile(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is 
usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the 
local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.  in 
Command line code on line 1

Warning: readfile(http://symfony.com/installer): failed to open stream:
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is usually a temporary 
error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not 
receive a response from an authoritative server.  in Command line code on 
line 1
```

I could not find any help on Symfony website about alternative installation method.

Comment: Wich version of windows do you used ? It's maybe a dns problem.

Comment: Windows 10 and also I tried the same on Mac Yosemite too.

Comment: ok. Your have a hostname problem. We need more informations about your machine and php version.

Comment: is php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony unable to download anything ? If that's the case only then you have a dns issue. You may try https://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/opendns-ip-addresses/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The problem was with PHP Version (was using old Xampp).

After running the command:
    php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony

I have to run the symfony application like:
    php symfony

It works perfectly now. Thanks all for the support.